# In Flex, how do I get the value of a ComboBox that is in a dataGrid?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, combobox

I have a data grid that has ComboBoxes in two of its columns.

What I need to do is get the values of those bombo boxes when a user highlights the row of the grid NOT when the user uses the comboBox. I understand how to pull the values out once the change handler is invoked on the comboBox, but I'm not seeing a way to get at the comboBoxes that belong to the currently highlighted gridRow.

I'm sure it's really straight forward, but I'm just not able to find any reference on how it's done. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you override the set data function of the itemRenderer to set the initial values?

Comment: no, the initial values are set by a data provider array... why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok assuming the data field that the ComboBox is in is driven by a data field named 'foo'

and the dataGrid itself has an id of 'dg'...

var currentVal:String = dg.dataProvider.getItemAt(dg.selectedIndex).foo;

Answer (score 0):

The DataProvider of the DataGrid should have the correct values if the ComboBox ItemEditor has been correctly implemented.